# SWIFT: AVPlayerViewController Video not loading on mobile data

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer, avplayerviewcontroller

I am trying to play a video whose URL is coming from server. Video is playing with wifi but not on mobile data. Please let me know what I am doing wrong?

**Code:**

```
//Variables
var player : AVPlayer!
let vc = AVPlayerViewController()

//View Did Load
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    playVideo("//SomeUrl")
}

//Play Video
func playVideo(_ url:URL) {
    player = AVPlayer(url: url)
    vc.player = player
    player.automaticallyWaitsToMinimizeStalling = false
    vc.delegate = self
    vc.showsPlaybackControls = false
    vc.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill

    let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
    playerLayer.opacity = 0
    self.isVideoPlaying = true
    self.vc.player?.play()
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(wallDeadline: .now()+0.2) {
        self.vc.view.frame = self.view.window!.bounds
        self.vc.view.backgroundColor = .clear
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.vc.view.addSubview(self.viewOuter)
        }
        self.view.window?.addSubview(self.vc.view)
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the server you are trying to reach is not blocked by your mobile data provider ? If you try with an other video library or if you try to open the video url in Safari what's happening ?

Comment: I tried it on safari also. The video is not loading on mobile data. But when i tried it on wifi its works.

Comment: Then I think the issue is not related to AVPlayer, you should ask your data provider if the server you're trying to reach is blocked by them and if there is a way to bypass this. Did you try changing your DNS on the device you're using ? Maybe try with google dns (8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4)

Comment: As my server is not secure yet. My video url is something like this : http://*****************/15873588591587358818418.mp4

Comment: Do one thing, Download the same video and upload it google drive and try to play video from google drive URL. If your video played from drive then there is an issue with your server. If you're not able to play video from a drive then it is an issue related to data provider

Comment: Video is playing on wifi but not on mobile data